# What is the difference between Reversing Ring and Reverse Protect Ring?

Tags: lens, macro

I want buy a  Macro Reversing Ring for Macro shot but then I can't protect the lens with
a filter. Can I use Reverse Protect Ring for lens filter (like UV filer) or lens Cap?

Comment: I have also same issue, I have nikon d3200 and have a Reverse ring but how can I add a protector or lense filter to the open area of the lense? Is there any adapter to hold any filter on reverse lense?

Comment: "Protective" filters don't protect lenses near as much as most people think they do, and their flat surfaces can introduce a lot of unwanted reflections that can result in lens flare, ghosting, and a general reduction in optical quality. Just say "no" to protective filters and let your lens reach its potential image quality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people [cut a hole in a rear lens cap](http://www.davidkennardphotography.com/blog/826-how-to-make-a-filter-adapter-rear-element-protector-for-reversed-lens-macro.xhtml) and then attach a step ring to which they can add a filter. Others just try to be careful when shooting with a reversed lens.

**Update:** As explained in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/is-there-any-protection-ring-available-for-reversed-lenses), if you look hard enough you can find a commercial version of the same thing -- a [rear mount adapter that holds 58mm filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/is-there-any-protection-ring-available-for-reversed-lenses).